# Event listener requires two clicks before DOM is updated

Tags: javascript, rest

My webpage has a table with data that is pulled from a database - it's pretty much a clone of the database. Each row in the table has one delete button and one update button, which allows the user to delete the respective database row, or update the columns using a supplied form.

My problem is that both the delete and update buttons aren't working properly. The first click makes the appropriate change to the database, but the table remains unchanged until the button is clicked a second time.

```
let loadUsers = function () {
fetch("http://localhost:8080/users").then(function (response) {
    response.json().then(function (data) {
    // generate table and delete/update button html
    data.forEach(function (user) {
        deleteButton = document.querySelector("#btn-del-user);
        deleteButton.onclick = function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + user.firstname + "?")) {
            deleteUser(user.id);
            loadUsers();
        }
        });
    }
    });
};

loadUsers();


document.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#update-user-form')) return;

  let elements = document.querySelector('#update-user-form').elements;
  let inputs = {
    "firstName": elements.firstName.value,
    "lastName": elements.lastName.value,
    "email": elements.email.value,
    "password": elements.password.value
  };
  let body = "";

  // create a URL-encoded string from form inputs
  Object.keys(inputs).forEach(function (key, i) {
    body += key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(inputs[key]);
    if (i < Object.keys(inputs).length - 1) {
      body += "&";
    }
  });

  let id = elements["user-id"].value;

  fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/' + id, {
    method: 'UPDATE',
    body: body,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

loadUsers();
});
```

The weird part is that I have a separate form on the page that lets me add new rows to the table/database, and the listener for that form also calls `loadUsers()`, but that successfully updates the DOM after a single click.

Comment: your fetch in the submit handler does nothing with the result of the fetch

Comment: I removed some lines in an attempt to clean things up but I probably took out too much. I added them back to the original post.

Comment: Now that you've edited the submit handler ... *your fetch in the submit handler does nothing with the result of the fetch*

Comment: Do I need to do something with the result? I only have the server returning a status code for an UPDATE request, not any data. The UPDATE fetch updates the database, and then `loadUsers()` fires a GET request to get the database changes. If i'm doing something wrong I don't know what.

Comment: I guess not - does `loadUsers` expect that the UPDATE has finished? (yes, it does, this is your problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loadUsers would need to wait for the update/delete to finish before loading the users again

try

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/' + id, {
    method: 'UPDATE',
    body: body,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).then(loadUsers);
```